# UFW ignores his rules

Tags: firewall, ufw

I often search in the access.log for IP of services that do not interest me (E. Semrush, Mj12bot, Megaindex etc.) and add them to UFW.

But often adding the rule to UFW responds like this:

```
ufw deny from 46.229.173.137 to any;
Skipping adding existing Rule
```

The rule existed but was ignored?

After adding a rule I always do also:

```
ufw reload
```

And sometimes I also restart the server.

My server is on Vultr, Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Why are UFW's rules ignored? Is it Vultr's fault? Ubuntu's fault? UFW's fault?

ufw status here:
https://pastebin.com/6HS1ZgiA
(Too long to post here)

Example IP in acces.log: http://i63.tinypic.com/dnetu1.png

Comment: You answered your own question - "
I often search in the access.log for IP of services that do not interest me (E. Semrush, Mj12bot, Megaindex etc.) and add them to UFW.

But often adding the rule to UFW responds like this:

ufw deny from 46.229.173.137 to any;
Skipping adding existing Rule
The rule existed but was ignored?" . You would need to post all your rules if you need them reviewed, but the message indicates this is a duplicate

Comment: Ok, but if it is a duplicate means that the rule already existed and today there was still an access from this IP...

Comment: I can not advise you one way or another from what little you posted. Need firewall rules + logs or whatever makes you feel it is not working. Order of rules is important so you may well be accepting traffic earlier for all I know

Comment: I added a link to my UFW status

Comment: That is rule 1050 so it already exists. What makes you think it is not blocked?

Comment: Because the rule exists for months and today I found an access from that IP, the rule would have to prevent access, but it did not.

Comment: What access did you find ? You still have not posted that part of your question.

Comment: I launched this "tail /var/log/apache2/access.log" on my server 2 hours ago and I have not saved it, now it is gone... but it did not happen only today, I have already seen in the past IP blocked, in theory blocked by ufw, in my access.log

Comment: You need to post logs. Logs do not disappear unless you delete them or you have a cracker who erases their tracks.

Comment: So, my links are not postable here because the site is 18+, but trust me, in my logs there is that IP blocked.

Comment: You can edit your question and provide the log entries in question.

Comment: I posted an image

Comment: If your firewall is enabled you will have to file a bug report. You have a long long long list of blacklisted IP and I am guessing you have an accept early in your rule set you did not post . You really need to post all your rules.

Comment: Your "80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)    " and other apache rules is probably hit before your blacklist

Comment: You can list all your rules, in order, and see where the traffic is going, with iptables. `sudo iptables -L -v -n`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found, it was the order of the rules.

I have manually moved all the ALLOW rules down and all the DENY rules at the top in the file /etc/ufw/user.rules and reload ufw, and now the load on my server is MUCH lower .

Maybe that was enough, in the coming days I still looking for blocked IP in my access.log, hoping not to find them.